# Tilemaps.Tilemap.SetTile() supposedly doesn't exist(Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Relevant piece of code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Tilemaps;

public class Generation : MonoBehaviour
{
    private int[,] CavePoints;

    public RuleTile Stone;

    public Camera Camera;

    private int CurrentMapLength = 0;

    private void Awake()
    {
        SewerGeneration(5);
    }

    void Start()
    {
        PlaceGrid();
    }

    public void SewerGeneration
    {
        *Code*
    }

    //Place Tiles on grid

    private void PlaceGrid()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < CurrentMapLength + 1; x++) //width of map
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < 56; y++) //height of map
            {
                try
                {
                    if (CavePoints[x, y] == 1)    //CHANGE TO CavePoints
                    {
                        Tilemap.SetTile(new Vector3Int(x, y, 0), Stone);
                    }
                }catch (System.Exception e)
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, the Tilemap.SetTile() under the function `PlaceGrid()` returns:

`Assets/Scripts/Generation.cs(124,25): error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Tilemap.SetTile(Vector3Int, TileBase)'`

I then added Tilemaps. in front of the SetTile, and the code returned this:

`Assets/Scripts/Generation.cs(124,25): error CS0103: The name 'Tilemaps' does not exist in the current context`

Adding UnityEngine and removing Tilemap also yielded similar results.

Help appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Is `Tilemap` instanciated? If not and if `SetTile()` is not a static function, this may be the reason, take a look at [Error CS0120 documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0120)

Comment: It's a class made by Unity, so it should be included in UnityEngine, specifically UnityEngine.Tilemaps.

Comment: Don't you have to give it a value? Like you did with `public Camera Camera;` and, I presume, assigned a value in the editor interface. You may have imported this from Unity but it seems that it needs you to assign a value to it before using it, else Unity won't be able to know what Tilemap you want to target to `.SetTile()`

Comment: The syntax is SetTile(Vector3Int[A 3 dimensional vector], Tile[The actual tile we're setting the coordinates specified by the Vector3Int to]), so no value necessary

Comment: @Energia360 what Error404... means by `the value` is a proper reference to an **instance** of a `Tilemap` like `public Tilemap myTilemap;` -> reference your tilemap component here via the Inspector in Unity => change your code to `myTilemap.SetTile(....)`

Answer (score 0):

as the error tells you [`Tilemap.SetTile`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Tilemaps.Tilemap.SetTile.html) is **not** a `static` method.

You cannot simply call it via the type like

```
Tilemap.SetTile(...);
```

you rather need a reference to an instance of `Tilemap` e.g. like

```
[SerializeField] private Tilemap myTilemap;
```

assign this via the Inspector in Unity by drag&drop the according object/component into that field and then do

```
myTilemap.SetTile(...);
```